# Acumatica link sales order to existing purchase order

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica we can mark a sales order as "Mark for PO" and create a linked purchase order.  However there are instances where we need to link a sales order to an existing purchase order - in the case purchase order is created before the sales order or they are created separately.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to link a sales line to an existing PO.

After you mark the Sales line ("Mark for PO" is checked) you can click on the "PO LINK" button on the Document Details grid. From the pop up Purchasing Details panel you will see all available purchase orders for the selected item. Select the purchase order(s) you want to link and click save.

See image for example:

[image]